# Regular Expression that having atleast two / any where

Tags: c#, regex

I need one regular expression for c# which must have first letter `w` or `W` and whole textbox value must have two `/`.

Whole text can be alphanumeric or digit but must have two `/` and first letter `W` or `w`.

Comment: Do you have some sample texts which should be good and which should be bad? And have you tried anything yet?

Comment: hey i need one or more digit after last / and between two / some alphanumeric or number should be there. Please help.

Comment: You haven't answered my question...

Comment: @user3454831 have you checked my answer i just remodified vasili answer to match your requirement and it is working fine..!! You can check the demo

Comment: ^[wW].[A-Za-z0-9]*?\/.[A-Za-z0-9]*?\/.[0-9]*?$ .. i had tried this but after w it also allowing the special character.. i dont want it .please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[wW].*?\/.*?\/*[0-9]$
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cC8xW3)

Comment: hey after [wW] i need only alphanumeric and 0-9 .. i have tried this

Comment: ^[wW].[A-Za-z0-9]*?\/.[A-Za-z0-9]*?\/.[0-9]*?$ .. i had tried this but after w it also allowing the special character.. i dont want it .please help.

Answer (score 0):

This expression will do it:

```
^[wW].*?\/.*?\/.*?$
```

http://regex101.com/r/fU6uX9

Comment: hey i need this type of entries like Wa/bb/cc or W0/a9/w2 or W12a/av/cd .. so it wil work or not?

Comment: Try it on the demo site and see :) it works

Comment: hey i need one or more digit after last / and between two / some alphanumeric or number should be there. Please help.

Comment: ^[wW].[A-Za-z0-9]*?\/.[A-Za-z0-9]*?\/.[0-9]*?$ .. i had tried this but after w it also allowing the special character.. i dont want it .please help.